# How to delete subdirectories

Tags: c#, directory

Lets say a have some path:
**C:\Temp\TestFolder1\TestFolder2**

And I have some template:
**C:\Temp**

So I want to write function that will delete all subdirectories by template

```
void DeleteSubdirectories(string tlt, string path) {}
```

If I call this function with given parameters

```
DeleteSubdirectories("C:\Temp", "C:\Temp\TestFolder1\TestFolder2");
```

It must delete **TestFolder1\TestFolder2** subdirectories from '**C:\Temp**

What is the best way to write this function?

Answer (score 5):

If you desire to delecte "C:\Temp" too, use this:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"C:\Temp", true);
```

If you just want to delete the sub directories use this:

```
foreach (var subDir in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp").GetDirectories()) {
    subDir.Delete(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete("Path", true);
```

Comment: If I call this method like that:
    Directory.Delete(@"C:\Temp\TestFolder1\TestFolder2", true);
It will be delete only **TestFolder2**

I don't want to delete all subdirectories from Temp folder and Temp folder itself. I only want to delete folders that are in the Path parameter. In this case: **TestFolder1\TestFolder2**

Comment: @Alex, pardon me, I couldn't realize what you meant. Anyway, if you are after to delete `TestFolder1` from `Temp`, you have to use `System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"C:\Temp\TestFolder1", true);` that deletes the desired directory and its subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Directory.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) - the overload I linked has a boolean value that indicates if subdirectories should also be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds wierd, but try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

static void DeleteSubDirectories(string rootDir, string childPath)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, childPath);

    Directory.Delete(fullPath);

    string nextPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);

    while (nextPath != rootDir)
    {
        Directory.Delete(nextPath);
        nextPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(nextPath);
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
DeleteSubdirectories("C:\Temp", "TestFolder1\TestFolder2");
```

Obviously, you'll have to implement the exception handling.