# Delete SubFolders in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating an upload page for my sample program in ASP.NET. Now I am uploading student documents `certificates,marksheets` in my local storage and I am saving that file in specific directory.`D:\Vinayak\Student\Profiledocs\610\myfile.txt` Upload was worked successfully.

Now I am delete a specific student profile documents in my local storage using my ASP.NET page.

`D:\Vinayak\Student\Profiledocs\610\myfile.txt` is my file storage directory.

Now how I am to delete this sub folder and files `\610\myfile.txt`.

`610` is a column value named by `studentid` in my `student details`
table.

If I am select any student id like `610 or 12` whatever it is.

The student files are saved in my parent folder `Profiledocs`.
like this

```
\Profiledocs\610\myfile.txt
\Profiledocs\121\myfile1.txt
\Profiledocs\321\myfile2.txt
```

Now what I am make to delete the sub folders and files in my parent folder `Profiledocs`

Comment: `Directory.Delete(@"D:\Vinayak\Student\Profiledocs\610", true);`? - remove `\610` folder with all its content?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342042/how-to-delete-subdirectories and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory

Comment: how your student id created?

Comment: so you want to delete the entire 610 folder basically, not just that file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all files and folders in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Comment: @NicolasTyler  i already seen that [How to delete all files and folders in a directory?] but it wont use for me.

Comment: @vinayakvk Yet your selected answer is a slight variant of that answer. You can't expect the StackOverflow community to do your work for you. Please read through this before asking another question: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below method to delete sub folder and its content by passing `studentId` as parameter.

```
private static void DeleteSubFolderAndContent(int studentId)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(@"D:\Vinayak\Student\Profiledocs", studentId.ToString());   
    Directory.Delete(path, true);
}
```

You can use above function like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DeleteSubFolderAndContent(610); // <= "610" comes from database

    Console.WriteLine("Sub Folder and Its Content Deleted Successfully");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Note:** Make sure that your upload folder have full access control to read and write.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thanks for improvement, answer updated :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the full file path, and you wish to delete its current directory. First you need to get the directory path.

```
fileDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
```

This piece of code below will delete all folders and files in your current directory.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fileDirectory);

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

Comment: If "you wish to delete its current directory", why the `foreach` loops and not just `new DirectoryInfo(fileDirectory).Delete(true);`?